# How to get size on disk of a directory C++

Tags: c++, filesystems, filesize, disk, utility

How do you get the size on disk using C++ code and not the file size?

I am trying to get the size on disk of a directory(folder), and adding up the file sizes only gives the actual file size. What I need is the size on disk, is there anyway to get that?

Thank you

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
#include <filesystem>
using namespace std::filesystem;
int main(size_t argc, char* argv[])
{
   if (argc == 1) {
        void rscan3(path const&, unsigned i = 0);
        rscan3(".");

    }
}
void rscan3(path const& f, unsigned i) {
    string indent(i, ' ');
    uintmax_t size = 0;
    for (auto d : directory_iterator(f)) {

        size += d.file_size();
        cout << indent << "Folder = " << absolute(f).string() << " SIZE: " << size << endl;
        if (is_directory(d.status())) 
            rscan3(d.path(), i + 2);

    }
}
```

Comment: An empty directory size is 0 bytes. (You can do the experiment on windows, I am not sure about other systems)... I thing the whole size of a directory is just the sum of its files' sizes.

Comment: That’s system-dependent. On Linux, there is a “real” directory size which is a size occupied by the directory itself (i.e. by the file list), and the “total” directory size which is sum of *on-disk* sizes of the content. On-disk file size is that actually occupied, and is usually greater than “apparent” file size as the space is allocated in blocks (but may be smaller as well if filesystem-level compression is used).

Comment: @GhaziMajdoub "An empty directory size is 0 bytes." - That's *obviously* wrong. Even an empty directory *has to* occupy some space on disk as an entry in its parent directory - the name of the directory takes up space and depending on the filesystem it may take up more space than just the name. No way zero bytes is correct.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I created an empty directory and checked the size (on properties): It says 0 bytes. But, obviously, it certainly has to have a size; I agree. (Now, how useful is it to account for the few bytes it occupies?)

Comment: @GhaziMajdoub It isn't just a 'few bytes' though.  The space occupied by a file system entry is a multiple of the block size -- typically 4k these days.

Comment: @GhaziMajdoub   "I created an empty directory and checked the size" - No. You checked the size *as reported by Windows*, that's not the same as the actual size on disk. And as to why it's useful to account for every last byte, you'll have to ask OP. They may be working on an extremely space constrained system where every byte counts. Who knows why it's important - I don't, but I *do know* that the information you are posting is *not* correct.

Comment: I am trying to find a way to retrieve the "size on disk" of a file or folder. Really just wondering how that size is calculated, because I could not get it just by file_size(). Was wondering what Windows does to get that value.

Comment: @JJ Windows reports a "size on disk" of 0 bytes for empty directories. If your software is destined to Windows, it seems like the OS does not give much importance to the size it occupies... And the STL `filesystem::file_size` works only for files, it throws an exception for directories: `filesystem error: cannot get file size: Is a directory`.

Comment: @JJ When you check for a directory containing many sub-directories/files, you might notice the reported size on Properties builds up progressively... which infers the system is iterating recursively through sub-directories/files to sum all files sizes... You can do an experiment to check if the full size really equals the sum of all individual files (directories excluded).

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified in comments you are asking about Windows:

A file is indicated by an entry in the file index or file table (MFT for NTFS, FAT for FAT file system). This table is located in special position of the physical filesystem (e.g. harddisk) and holds address and meta data of each file. The file size is actual amount of space taken up by the file; this can be zero or any larger size. When a file has no data, it is empty (size = 0).

In Windows filesystems, size of a directory is the total sum of all files (and files in sub-folders) in it. So, an empty directory has size zero.

[Source: Why does an empty folder have zero bytes on Windows?](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-an-empty-folder-have-zero-bytes-on-Windows)

The STL `filesystem::file_size` works only for files, it throws an exception for directories: `filesystem error: cannot get file size: Is a directory [dir]`. Why? Because a directory is just an entry in the file index or table.

On Windows, when you check for a directory containing many sub-directories/files, you might notice the reported "size on disk" on Properties builds up progressively; which infers the system is iterating recursively through sub-directories/files to sum all files sizes... You can do an experiment to check if the full size really equals the sum of all individual files (directories excluded).